# How to send a value to server with post method?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm working with JS from the last few days, and I'm implementing chat feature.
I am using AJAX post method to send and receive texts,but the problem is that the code I've written isn't working well.

**JS code**

```
function getPeople(room_code) {
    console.log(room_code);
    $.ajax({
        url: "process_php/Getroompeople.php" , 
        data: {
            roomcode: room_code
            } ,
        cache: false ,
        processData: false ,
        type: "POST" ,
        success: function(response) {
            //implementPeople(response);
            console.log(response);

        }
    });

        setTimeout(function(){ getPeople(room_code); }, 1000);
    }
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php
$room_code = $_POST["roomcode"];
echo $room_code;
echo "hello";
?>
```

The response says undefined index.

So, any help with that would be very helpful to me!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I've given value to room_code before running that function, so according to me that shouldnt be a big deal.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
 getPeople("111111");
</script>`

Comment: Are you getting the value of `$room_code` in PHP? Or to put it in some other way, is the PHP URL you have entered in `url` parameter in JavaScript is right?

Comment: yes Everything is in its proper place

Comment: @helloworld Use ajax error function

Comment: is the value printed to the console?

Comment: @mplungjan — Why? It's an argument name, so it is already a local variable in the scope of the function. Defining it before the function just creates a variable that is never used.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting "processData" to true.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing an object to `data`.

> ```
>     data: {
>         roomcode: room_code
>         } ,
> ```

Under normal circumstances, jQuery will process this object and convert it into the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data format.

PHP will automatically parse `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data and use it to populate `$_POST`.

---

However, you also said:

> ```
>    processData: false ,
> ```

… which tells jQuery not to process it. So it will get treated as a plain string (i.e. `"[object Object]"`) and sent to PHP.

Your data doesn't exist in that string, so `$_POST["roomcode"]` isn't defined.

---

**Remove `processData: false ,`** (or set it to `true`)